# response from driver in rest api of laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want to get response from driver whenever request is made

```
$ride=DB::table('ride')->get()->where('status','')->toArray();
```

table 'ride' have these attributes

```
id,driver_id,vehicle_id,order_id,status
```

whenever user complete the order form, his request should pass to driver so he will decide weather he accept user request or reject it. everything is ok the form is submitting fine but i don't have any idea how to tackle with response of driver .i wanna create a table say ride_requests which will handle all the upcoming requests, trigger events whenever a request is made to the driver

Comment: What are your ideas? What have you tried so far? Where exactly do you need help?

Comment: currently i just request a ride in which i give my current location and drop off location to the specific driver